# Update mysql Database - am I doing it right?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have about 15 tables that are linked together in my database (mariadb - parent-child with FK).

If I now update something with VBA (over ADODB, mysql-connector), I update first with my code the necessary "Child" tables with the new IDs/values first, close these tables and then add this new IDs/values to the "Parent" table. Otherwise, there is also an error if I first update the value in the "parent" table but not in the linked tables. I have found out that it is probably because of my "restrict" instead of "update" setting. Since it works that way and it was a lot of work to write the code (much code) I would leave it that way. Is this a problem and not common or can I leave it like this (-> update all child tables and then the parent table at the end)?

Am I going the right way or is it completely inconvenient to write the code like that? But what would the usual way?

Comment: Are you talking about `FOREIGN KEYs`?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (Note:  FKs are not a mandatory part of database tables.)

Comment: yes FK = Foreign Keys. yes I know but only if it is correct in principle to update several linked tables like this

Comment: Do you have all the `UPDATEs` in a single `BEGIN`...`COMMIT` transaction?

Comment: I connect to each table with my string (select * from "tablename") and than change/add values and .update this table. Than I close this connection and connecto to my next table...

Comment: Terminology - One "connects" to the MariaDB instance.  Then one performs multiple queries (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, etc) against multiple tables.  Only when finished with all the work does one "disconnect".  It is OK to go back and forth between tables while still "connected".  Please provide a subset of your SQL statements.  (2-3 tables, not all 15).  Currently, the discussion is too abstract.